# How to include an image in the user registration using the module Services

Tags: media, services

As the scheme would be to post a picture in the picture user or field in another field custom image. I tested with the following scheme and get nothing. The other fields in the record, user, password, custom text fields do not have any problem, but the images do not get anything. This is the Json object built for the image:

`www.xxxx.com/endpoint_services/user/register`  (Method POST)

```
{"name":"test"
,"mail":"test@example.com","pass" :{ "pass1" : "123456", "pass2" : "123456" },
 "field_categoria": {      "und":  { "tid": "1" } },
    "field_cif": {   "und": [  { "value": "xxxxxxx" }  ]  },
  "field_imagen_usuario":{"und": [ 
    { "filename": "testExample.jpg", 
    "filepath": "public://testExample.jpg",
     "filemime": "image/jpeg" ,
     "file": "/iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQ...." } ] } }
```

All other fields work perfectly, but the image is no way to get it to. I can do to resolve this?

(I also replaced by "target_uri" "filepath" and does not work)

Comment: You need to first create the file to get it's newly created file id, then you attach it via the `target_id` on the field: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-services-file-create-example-json-and-jquery